# books: boldface for math in chapter titles, table of contents and fancyhdr

Tags: math-mode, table-of-contents, chapters, fancyhdr, bold

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{Test}
\author{Me}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\chapter{$1+1=2$} % normal face everywhere
\lipsum[1-5]
\chapter{$\mathbf{1+1=2}$} % bold face everywhere
\lipsum[5-10]
\chapter[$4+4=8$]{$\mathbf{4+4=8}$} % bold face in title, normal face in toc and header
\lipsum[10-15]

\end{document}
```

The three chapters all have math in their titles. Naturally, I want them to behave nicely, that is,

- bold face when printed on the chapter title page,
- bold face when printed in the table of contents,
- normal face when printed in the header.

The first two conditions are easy to meet by using `\mathbf` in the chapter titles (as done for the second chapter), but then, the bold face also appears in the header. When using normal face in the optional argument title, it also disappears from the line in the table of contents.

How can I have the correct boldface/normalface behavior for math in chapter titles when using the `book` document class and `fancyhdr`?

Comment: You can use `\boldmath`; e.g., \chapter{\boldmath Chapter $1+1=2$}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `\protect\boldmath` in your `\chaper` title (since it's a moving argument) and set `\let\boldmath\relax` as part of your [`fancyhdr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) construction:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{amsfonts,fancyhdr,lipsum}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% Remove header rule
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[RE,LO]{\let\boldmath\relax\leftmark}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{\protect\boldmath${1+1=2}$}
\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```